# CSS conditional image scaling

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to scale down an image only if width is higher than XX pixels, in HTML/CSS ?

Comment: The definitive article on fluid images: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use max-width in your css to fix a maximum image width and don't specify your image height.
This way your image should stay proportionnal and respect a max width.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `max-width` or `max-height` to specify the largest you want the image to be.

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MsyPL/)**

**References**

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Max-height

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Max-width

As noted in the comments this is not supported in IE6 or below.

Comment: I'm not sure if max-width is ok with IE.

Comment: It's only a problem in IE 6 and below.

Comment: @Whiskas: `max-width` isn’t supported by IE 6 (aside from [some trickery](http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/)), but it’s fine in later versions of IE, and all other browsers.